# rails 'where' not searching the date to match

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So heres the code i have:

```
 viaurldb = Via.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? ', "%#{tmname}%", "tmdate").first
```

I was wondering why this above code isn't getting the things out of the Via table, that matches `product_name` to `tmname` and `specifications` to `tmdate`

any help would be great

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that the your table does not have **tmdate** value from its **specification** field.

But if **tmdate** is a variable, you must change your code to the following.

```
viaurldb = Via.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND specifications = ? ', "%#{tmname}%", "#{tmdate}").first
```